# Querying MongoDb's custom key & value with Index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, key-value, key-value-store

I am trying to store key value data in MongoDb. 
**Key** could be any string and I don't know about it anything more before storing, **value** could be any type (int, string, array). And I would like to have an index on such **key** & **value**.

I was looking on a ([Multikey Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)) over an array of my **key-vals** but looks like it can't cover queries over array fields.

Is it possible to have an index on a custom **key** & **value** in mongoDb and make queries with such operations as $exists and $eq and $gte, $lte, $and, $or, $in without COLLSCAN but through an IXSCAN stage?
Or maybe I need another Db for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question but I think that this is precisely where MongoDB's strengths are - dealing with different shapes of documents and data types.

So let's say you have to following two documents:

```
db.test.insertMany([
    {
        key: "test",
        value: [ "some array", 1 ]
    },
    {
        key: 12.7,
        values: "foo"
    }
])
```

and you create a [compound](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) index like this:

```
db.test.createIndex({
    "key": 1,
    "value": 1
})
```

then the following query will use that index:

```
db.test.find({ "key": "test", "value": 1 })
```

and also more complicated queries will do the same:

```
db.test.find({ "key": { $exists: true }, "value": { gt: 0 } })
```

You can verify this by adding a `.explain()` to the end of the above queries.

**UPDATE based on your comment:**

You don't need the aggregation framework for that. You can simply do something like this:

```
db.test.distinct("user_id", { "key": { $exists: true } })
```

This query is going to use the above index. Moreover it can be made even faster by changing the index definition to include the `"user_id"` field like this:

```
db.test.createIndex({
    "key" : 1.0,
    "value" : 1.0,
    "user_id" : 1
})
```

This, again, can be verified by running the following query:

```
db.test.explain().distinct("user_id", { "key": { $exists: true } })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have one more issue on that. I have users and each user can have a lot on such key & value pairs (so it will be like {"user_id":5,"key":"test","value":11} for each key & value), and I would like to query mongoDb to get all users with key_val1 exists, key2 not exists, key_val3 grater that 10. Looks like I need to use mongodb aggregation here, will it work fast enough or will it use compound index on user_key_val for such query?

Comment: Thank you, distinct() function over key and value filtering is that what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your `key` can be any arbitrary value, then this is impossible. Your best bet is to create an index on some other known field to limit the initial results so that the inevitable collection scan's impact is reduced to a minimum.